# How to pass a parameter by URL to the JavaScript code on GAE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-app-engine

I'd like to pass a parameter in request URL to the JavaScript code on GAE environment.

For example, following URL was entered.

http://example.com:8080/hello?key=abc

The hello page was rendered with hello.py and hello.tmpl which are shown below respectively.

```
'''hello.py'''
key = self.request.get('key')

{# hello.tmpl #} 
<html>
  <div id="key">{{ key }}</div>
  <script src="hello.js"></script>
</html>
```

In order to refer the key specified with URL in hello.js, the function can be written as following.

```
// hello.js
function() {
  console.log($('#key').text());
};
```

It works well and meets my original request that a parameter was propagated from the URL to the JavaScript Code.

However, I felt like it's not a smart way. I used div tag as a buffer between URL and JavaScript code. Does anyone know any smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use data extension instead of adding a div:

```
<body data-key='{{key}}'>
  <...>
</body>

// hello.js
function() {
  console.log($('body').data('key'));
};
```